# Proving that a Bipartite graph with has a perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have a bipartite graph $G$ with $n$ vertices in each partition. It is given to us that each vertex on one side has a degree at least $\frac{n}{2}$. I'm supposed to prove that $G$ has a perfect matching.

I'm having a hard time proving this because it seems false. Say $G$ is a bipartite graph with 4 vertices on each side of the partition. Let $A$ = the partition of $G$ s.t. degree of every node in $A \geq \frac{n}{2}$. We can make every vertex in $A$ be incident exactly to 2 vertices in $B$, where $B$ = the rest of the vertices not in $A$.

Doesn't this fit our criterion: both sets of vertices = $n$ and for every vertex $\in A$ it has a degree  $\geq \frac{n}{2}$? But there isn't a perfect matching in this graph.

E.g.

A partition    B partition

1              5

2              6

3              7

4              8

For each vertex in $A$, there is an edge between $v_i \in A$ and vertices $5$ and $6$ $\in B$.

Comment: yeah, it seems to be false, are you sure you are reading the theorem correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't that every vertex has degree at least $n/2$?

Comment: Here is the exact statement: Let G be a bipartite graph with n vertices in each side of the bipartition. Suppose that the degree of each vertex on one side is at least n/2. Show that G has a perfect matching.

Comment: You provide a very convincing counterexample. Perhaps your teacher/course/book assumes implicitly that every graph is connected? Is there someone you can contact with your concern (teacher of the course, teaching assistant, etc.)? I don't think the MSE community can be of great help here...